# Magnolia CMS: Dialogs too wide

Tags: magnolia

I have here a magnolia 6.2.3 installation where the edit dialogs are too wide (full screen width):

[image: full width edit dialog]

I compared the markup with the markup from demo author and noticed that some css classes are missing.
It looks good when i add the `medium` class to the root node of the markup.

How do I get magnolia to render the correct markup?

My guess was that I am using an outdated widgetset, but the `magnolia-vaadin-widgetset-pro:6.2.3` is used.

---

More information:

It is a migration from 5.5.8 to 6.2.3.
It affects all Magnolia 5 UI dialogs also system dialogs. It does not occur in the new Magnolia 6 UI apps like `pages-app` or `dam`.

See for example from the `About Magnolia` app:
[image: Jira login in dialog]
Markup:
[image]

As a counterexample, the same dialog from the demo instance:
[image]

---

**Edit2:**

Ok, it seems to be a problem with the specific Magnolia version. I can recreate the problem with `mgnl jumpstart -m 6.2.3`. With 6.2.4 the problem does not occur anymore. Unfortunately an update is no option, I will invest a few more hours to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the specific Magnolia version.

It can be easily reproduced with `mgnl jumpstart -m 6.2.3`.

Who can should **update**. It seems to be fixed in 6.2.4.

Unfortunately I can not update my project.
The most painful problem (description fields in the dialogs are not readable) I could fix by updating `magnolia-vaadin-widgetset-pro` to 6.2.4.

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood, the dialog definition for your dialog is set to be wide. See `wide` property of the dialog in the [dialog definition documentation](https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/6.2/Templating/Dialog-definition.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help, it affects all Magnolia 5 UI dialogs also system dialogs. 
I updated the question with more information and screenshots.